# Pointwise convergence on dense set extension

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Suppose that $f_n:X\rightarrow V$ is a sequence of continuous functions from a compact metric space $X$ to a Banach space $V$ and let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$.  Suppose that $A$ is a dense subset of $X$ and $f_n$ converge point-wise to $f$ on $A$.  Can we deduce that $f_n$ converge to $f$, $\mu$-a.e. on $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1]$, $V=\mathbb{R}$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ which is dense in $[0,1]$, and 
$$f_n(x)=\sin (\pi n!x) $$
Then $f_n\to 0$ on $A$, but $f_n \not \to 0$ on $[0,1]\setminus A$. Since $\mu(A)=0$, $f_n\not \to 0$ $\mu$-a.e.

Comment: But does there exist a subsequence that converges on all of [0,1] then?

Comment: My guess is no. Since $\left\{\sin n\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, I guess $\left\{\sin (\pi n!x)\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is too when $x$ is irrational. Then for all $x$ there is a subsequence of $f_n$ which converges to $0$ on  $x$. But the problem is that this subsequence is different for all irrational $x$ and these are uncountably many.

Comment: Good point, thanks :)